# iOS Chained Payment without buyer needing Paypal account - MPL and PayPal iOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

Using either MPL or PayPal iOS SDK - I need to implement chained payments in my iOS app without having a user needing to login with their Paypal account.

The github demo sample forces a user to login to make a chained payment.
https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/tree/gh-pages/MPL

Has anyone worked around this?
I assume this is not yet feasible with the new SDK

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the MPL doesn't offer up guest checkout functionality so your customers would need to login to a PayPal account to make the Chained Payment.  Also, you are correct that the new mSDK does not yet support Chained Payments.